# Use MOXY in CXF Environment without WSDL first approach

Tags: java, jax-ws, eclipselink, moxy

Currently, I have a running karaf server with blueprint, cxf and jax-ws. I used the class first approach, so I just have a created WSDL. I can request object via the defined service and everthing works fine.

Now I tried to use EclipseLink MOXY as my JAXB provider, due to more complex objects. But I didn't get it up and running.

I tried [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/leveraging-moxy-in-your-web-service-via-jax-ws-provider.html), but I don't have a created wsdl, and I don't like the idea writing all by myself only to get moxy running. Everything else in this example would be fine.
Is there any alternative way to use moxy in this combination: Karaf, blueprint, cxf, jax-ws?

More links:[Provider Service](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/provider-services.html), [Discussion](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/moxy-cxf-td5568009.html)